# Why does a vertical line have a SLOPE (steepness) of undefined?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, slope

[image: slope picture]

The curve shows :

- x goes 1 to right
- y goes up by 3

the `SLOPE` is defined as the ratio of *`rise`* to the *`step`*

SLOPE = rise/step = 3/1 = 3

Now that :

- Horizontal line has *`SLOPE`* of **0**.
- Vertical line has *`SLOPE`* of ***undefined***.

It makes sense for me to imagine horizontal line has *`SLOPE`* of **0** since there is no ***rise*** at all. But why the vertical has *`SLOPE`* of ***undefined***.?

Comment: https://sites.gpc.edu/tlamar2/files/2015/07/horizontalandverticallines-27emx7y.pdf or https://www.montereyinstitute.org/courses/Algebra1/COURSE_TEXT_RESOURCE/U04_L1_T1_text_final.html

Comment: Hey thks man, the first link very useful to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $dx$ (step) for a vertical line is 0 and the expression for slope
$$m=\frac{dy}{dx}$$
results in the bogeyman of mathematics, division by zero. That's why.

However, in some cases we define the slope of a vertical line as $\infty$. This implies $\frac 1{\infty}=0$ and vice versa, and is useful in projective geometry among other areas of mathematics.